# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797 Error While installing npm Appium

Tags: npm, installation, appium

I have just started to learn mobile automation - appium,

```
npm install -g appium
```

Above command line is throwing an error; please could someone help to resolve the issue, got stuck here for a long time.

Comment: "throwing me error" add error text